# Local Disk deleted css file, created new one, but cant link it to HTML doc

Tags: html, css

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Traditionals Barbershop</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="theme.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
    family=Roboto+Slab"rel="stylesheet "> 
</head>
```

this is the head to my HTML document, my computer somehow randomly deleted my CSS file mid-development, and when I copied the code and paste into a new file, save it under the same name, and reload the page, nothing happens. My HTML document refuses to link to my stylesheet. I have copied the code and even replicated it. tried different names, and even a new folder. if anyone could help me I would Greatly Appreciate it.

I am completely stumped....

CSS file ===

```
html,
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}
h1 {
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
}
h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.window-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.main-nav {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0);
  border-bottom: 3px solid #fdca64;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.header-logo {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.main-ul {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  list-style: none;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 40px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.main-li {
  margin: 0 1em;
}

a.nav-links {
  color: #fdca64;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #525050cc;
  transition: border 0.5s ease-in 0.5s;
}
/* activates hover transition */

.nav-links:hover {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.nav-links:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-bottom: solid 3px #fdca64;
  box-shadow: 3px 2px 9px 1px #211f1f;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
}

.nav-links:hover:after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
}

/******* End of Navigation *******/
.greeting-text {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  height: 8em;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.header-h1 {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255);
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  font-size: 4em;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 3px 2px #9c9797;
  word-spacing: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.slogan {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  top: 80%;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transform: translateY(-80%);
  text-shadow: 2px 1px #9c9797;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin: 0;
}
.showcase-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #000;
}

.header-image {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  width: 45%;
}

.main-imgs {
  max-height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px;
  border: 3px solid #fdca64;
}

/**** End Of Showcase ****/

.information-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
}

.section-2,
.section-3 {
  border: solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.slideshow-container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.rotated-image {
  width: 100%;
  border: green 5px solid;
}
.slides {
  display: none;
}
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}
.active,
.dov:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}
.fade {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.section-2 {
  width: 40%;
  max-height: 300px;
}
.section-2 h3 {
  font: italic bold 20px/30px Georgia, serif;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .header-image {
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0.5rem;
    width: 41%;
    display: flex;
  }

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 425px) {
  .header-image {
    min-width: 300px;
    left: 2%;
  }
  .main-imgs {
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 200px;
  }
  .header-h1 {
    font-size: 17px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .showcase-wrapper {
    width: 95%;
  }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing here anybody can use to help.

Comment: What would you like us to do? Is your css file in the same directory as your index file?

Comment: try `./theme.css`. And also make sure that the HTML document and the CSS file are on the same folder.

Comment: both files are in the same folder home/desktop/test(test = folder)

Comment: im completely mind blown by how my index file can't link to my css.

Comment: both files are in the same folder, the css file is named exactly as above.

Comment: tell me the information that is needed, and I will provide it.

Comment: How do you tell it is not linked? Maybe it would have linked but the styles were not applied due to some CSS error (missing braces)?

Comment: I my css doesn't have any errors. Only.about 300 lines of.code but it's all clean and everything is linked up. No errors that vsc is hitting either.

Comment: 404? 200 ok? Check your network requests to move forward. Fiddler or developer tools F12 to look further.

Comment: says status is finished = the index file is actually taking some styles but 80% of the styles are not being applied. mainly the navigation bar, my containers for my images, etc., just the color is taking affect basically. but only text color and background color.

Comment: when i use the inspector it has a lot of my rule sets grayed out.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity It might be specificity issue.

Answer (score 0):

when html document and css is in same folder or not you have to give path. I think it work without some mistake in your css file.

Comment: i just used it as "theme.css" and ./theme.css and ../theme.css and it still doesn't work, and both files are in the exact same folder, which live on my desktop

Answer (score 0):

Check your CSS for errors, also, you could try to disable the browser cache, if you are in Chrome, press F12, go to the Network tab, check Disable cache and reload the page.

**Edit:** I don't have enough reputation to write this as a comment: It would be useful to take a look at your CSS file.

**Edit 2:** Try to temporaly copy your CSS to another file, and in the linked file apply a basic style, something like `body { background: red }` to check if the files are being linked correctly. If they are, probably there is an error in your CSS. Do the browser console output something? Which browser are you using?

Comment: `Ctrl+F5` for a hard refresh. Clears browser cache :)

Comment: I thought ctrl+shift+r refreshed while clearing cache

Comment: so i created a new folder, copied the HTML document, and created a new one within the new folder. The HTML file linked to the new style sheet with the pink background. When i grab my styles from my old style sheet " that has the 300 lines of code" it doesn't work. i just went through my CSS and noticed Nothing wrong with it. i can post the code above. but it'll be long.

Comment: It seems like most of your styles are being overwritten, do the inspector say which file do the rules that overwrite yours come from? Try putting the `<link>` tag at the end of the header, after other `<link>` tags.